# Decimal part is lost when displaying the result of division

Tags: java, android

I'm fairly new to Android Studio. I've tried to create an app that calculates how much you can spend everyday based on you income. My problem is that it doesn't display any decimals. Heres the code:

```
package com.example.amazi.howmuchmoney;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText et1,et2;
TextView tvResult;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    tvResult=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            int num1=Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
            int num2=Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());

            int result=num1/num2;
            tvResult.setText("Each day you can spend "+result);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: change the datatype of result variable as double rather than int

Comment: what kind of decimal would you expect `int result` to hold, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Mathematical operations performed on integers are exact, therefore;

```
(int) 3 / (int) 2 = (int) 1
```

Using double as your data type will fix your problem, although;

```
Integer.parseInt
```

Will still return an integer value, try;

```
Double.parseDouble
```